# Contains Query on multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception, nullreferenceexception

How do I search multiple columns using LINQ to SQL when any one of the column could be null?

```
IEnumerable<User> users = from user in databaseUsers
        where
             user.ScreenName.Contains(search)
             || user.FirstName.Contains(search)
             || user.LastName.Contains(search)
        select user;
```

I keep getting this exception:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where  it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an  instance of
>   an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add not null condition `user.Property != null`

```
  IEnumerable<User> users = from user in databaseUsers
    where
         (user.ScreenName != null && user.ScreenName.Contains(search))
         || (user.FirstName != null && user.FirstName.Contains(search))
         || ( user.LastName != null && user.LastName.Contains(search))
    select user;
```

Comment: the null error was caused by the either the ScreenName, FirstName or the LastName being null. Putting in user.ScreenName != null and surrounding it and the Contains filter with brackets ( ) did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<User> users = from user in databaseUsers
where
     (user.ScreenName + ' ' + user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName).Contains(search)
select user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your user is a null entry, or your databaseUsers are not initialized.