# conditional check in predicate LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class which returns a predicate:

```
public class UserPredicateBuilder 
    {
        public Guid Id{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Role> Roles{ get; set; }
        public UserType UserType{ get; set; }


        protected override Expression<Func<User, bool>> Predicate
        {
            get
            {
                return l => l.UserType == UserType
                            && l.Id== Id
                            && Roles.Contains(l.Role);
            }
        }
    }

public enum UserType
{
   None,
   Admin,
   User,
   Guest
}

public enum Role
{
   None,
   Create,
   Delete,
   Update
}
```

Now, the `Predicate` property checks all of the fields. I want to check:
 - `Id` if it's not equal to `Guid.Empty`;
 - `UserType` if it's not equal to `None`;
 -  `Roles` in the same way, iterate via collection, select only not `None` elements and check it;

In the *traditional* way I can do this like that:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Role> Roles{ get; set; }
   public UserType UserType{ get; set; }

   public IList<User> GetUsers(some args)
   {
      IQueryable<User> query = ...;
      if(user.Id != Guid.Empty)
         query = query.Where(u=>u.Id == Id);

      if(user.UserType != UserType.None)
         query = query.Where(u=>u.UserType == UserType)

      ...

      return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

How to do this in my scenario? I found the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class, can you show me how to solve my problem with this class?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716). With "AND" predicates start with `var pred = Predicate.True<T>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (I'm not sure if I read your requirements correctly, but hopefully this is a valid starting point):

```
return l => (UserType == UserType.None || l.UserType == UserType)
          && (Id == Guid.Empty || l.Id == Id)
          && (!Roles.Any() || Roles.Where(r => r != Role.None).Contains(l.Role));
```

Comment: Yes, your code do works well. But, this code is unreadable. Do you use the `PredicateBuilder` class? Is it possible solve with it? Thanks.

Comment: Your predicate builder class has a `Predicate` property - I've simply provided the updated body, didn't want to repeat the whole class.