# Linq statement Where within a Where

Tags: linq

I am building a query tool for use by non technical staff to retrieve records from the database.

I have a form with various drop downs which can be selected by the user depending on what they are looking for.

I have come across a problem where my query is returning records that do not match the users selection.

I believe this is only happening when I am querying the joined tables.

I have the following:

```
results = results.Where(c => c.CustomerEnrollment
                  .Where(x => x.CustomerCategoryID == CustomerCategoryID)
                  .Any());

results = results.Where(c => c.CustomerEnrollment
              .Where(x => x.StartDate <= DateRangeStart && x.EndDate >= DateRangeStart)
              .Any());
```

This will return results for the correct category but not within the specified date range.

I have also tried:

```
results = results.Where(c => c.CustomerEnrollment
                          .Any(x => x.CustomerCategoryID == CustomerCategoryID));
```

Comment: Can you describe in words what you are trying to do? Return the customers that have enrolled in a specific category *outside* a specific date range?

Comment: can you please provide some data that we can look for

Comment: I want to return the Customers that were enrolled in a specific category and that enrollment is within a specific date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns categories that have any `CustomerEnrollment` having their Id, and also have any `CustomerEnrollment` in the the required data range, but these `CustomerEnrollment`s *are not necessarily the same*.

To make sure that you get categories with `CustomerEnrollment`s that fulfill both conditions you have to do:

```
results = results.Where(c => c.CustomerEnrollment
                  .Where(x => x.CustomerCategoryID == CustomerCategoryID
                           && x.StartDate <= DateRangeStart
                           && x.EndDate >= DateRangeStart)
                  .Any());
```

With [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) you can parametrize the conditions:

```
using LinqKit;
...

var pred = Predicate.True<CustomerEnrollment>();

if (CustomerCategoryID > 0)
    pred = pred.And(c => c.CustomerCategoryID == CustomerCategoryID);

if (DateRangeStart.HasValue)
    pred = pred.And(c => c.StartDate <= DateRangeStart
                      && c.EndDate >= DateRangeStart);

results = results.AsExpandable()
                 .Where(c => c.CustomerEnrollment.AsQueryable()
                     .Any(pred));
```

The combination of `.AsExpandable()` and `.AsQueryable()` appears to be the only way to avoid exceptions.

Comment: My problem is I am building the query on the fly based on user selection. Is there a solution around this?

Comment: [PredicatBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is _the_ tool for this. I haven't got time now, but if you wish I can give it a shot later. In the mean time you could take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716).

Comment: I have had a play around with this but unsure how to use it with the joined tables. If you did have time I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am getting the following error now:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Connectv4_1.Areas.CRM.Models.CustomerEnrollment>' to 'bool' on this line results = results.Where(c => c.CustomerEnrollment).Any(pred.Expand());

Comment: Sorry not sure which query you are referring to. The code works great until the last line. there is a closing bracket missing in your code by inserting this at the end i get the error does not contain a definition for any.

Comment: OMG, I'm afraid it doesn't work in nested predicates.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for your time on this.

Comment: I have been able to get this working using the first query above. Not ideal as I am repeating the date code in multiple where statements, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your date range check as;

Change:

```
x => x.StartDate <= DateRangeStart && x.EndDate >= DateRangeStart
```

To:

```
//StartDate should be greater than or equal to
//EndDate should be less than or equal to
//Also you are using same variable DateRangeStart to check start and end
x => x.StartDate >= DateRangeStart && x.EndDate <= DateRangeEnd
```