# Inclusive search (IQueryable) in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, webforms

I'm trying to populate a repeater with results based on specific check boxes being checked.

Table:

```
SearchTable    
----    
TableId - int(pk)
Name - varchar
Description - varchar
Active - bool
IsCheck1 - bool
IsCheck2 - bool
```

Function:

```
protected void btnCSumit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = _db.SearchTable.Where(x => x.Active);
    if(ckbOne.Checked)
        query = query.Where(x => x.isCheck1);
    if(ckbTwo.Checked)
        query = query.Where(x => x.isCheck2);

    query = query.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
    repResults.DataSource = query;
    repResults.DataBind();
}
```

The code works when ckbOne OR ckbTwo is true, 
but if ckbOne AND ckbTwo is true I need it to do something like this

```
query = query.Where(x => x.isCheck1 || x.isCheck2);
```

**Edit:** hopefully made the question a bit more informative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic where clause (OR) in Linq to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621450/dynamic-where-clause-or-in-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below.

```
_db.table.Where(x => x.Active && ((check1 && x.isCheck1) || (check2 && x.isCheck2)))
```

Comment: Fyi: This is boolean algebra.