# Passing empty string to EF6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

This code runs fine in the SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT [PassNumber] FROM [dbo].[Customers] WHERE [PassNumber] <> 'A'
```

This code also works as expected:

```
string query = "PassNumber <> 'A'";
DbSqlQuery<Customer> data = db.Customers.SqlQuery( string.Format("select * from customers where {0}", query) );
```

Now it is changed to exclude empty rows and this code works fine on SSMS:

```
SELECT [PassNumber] FROM [Customers] WHERE [PassNumber] <> ''
```

But I can't find a way to correctly format the query string. I have tried all possible combinations that I thought of, but the code throws an exception: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword '<>'."

```
string query = "PassNumber <> '' ";
DbSqlQuery<Customer> data = db.Customers.SqlQuery( string.Format("select * from customers where {0}", query) );
```

NOTE: For simplicity, the check for null value has been left out of the examples in the question.

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: You're probably escaping the apostrophe. Try "PassNumber <> ''''"; (4 apostrophes).

Comment: Can you post the entire sql, it seems like there is an error in your query string based on the error message.

Comment: @drneel That is the entire sql. The error is in how to correctly format the string to send the '' (double  apostrophes).

Comment: @drneel The exception is " Incorrect syntax near the keyword '<>'. "

Comment: You could always go with LEN(PassNumber) > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing this by raw SQL you should use:

```
db.Customers.SqlQuery("select * from customers where PassNumber <> @p0, string.Empty);
```

Or

```
db.Customers.SqlQuery("select * from customers where LEN(PassNumber) > 0);
```

Comment: To me the best answer is the comment you posted about LinkKit. I will accept this one here just to close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `LINQ` when querying in `EF`. Then everything might be easier:

```
var customerList = db.Customers.Where(c => c.PassNumber == string.Empty).ToList();
```

Comment: I wish I could, but the field name, ("PassNumber" in this case), must also be passed in the query something that I don't know how to do in LINK.

Comment: @BenJunior I don't understand... is `PassNumber` not a property of the `Customer` class?

Comment: @Gert Arnold The full query contains two parameters, the field name and the condition. It could be c => c.PassNumber >12   or c => c.State = "FL" . Passing two params is easy in SqlQuery , but not so easy in LINK.

Comment: @BenJunior Ah, is that the problem. Maybe you should look at predicate builders, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716

Comment: @BenJunior why is passing two parameter a problem in LINQ?  I don't see any problems with `list.Where(c=> c.PassNumber > 12 || c.State == "FL")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use

```
is null
```

clause on the SQL?
Or`is not null`

Comment: the IsNull works fine, but what  I need is to check for empty strings