# How to make efficient search with LINQ in MVC4?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am developing MVC4 application. I am developing one search page which contains 5 textboxes and search button in which only one textbox is mandatory field. Remaining are not mandatory. I want to have AND of all 5 textbox values. My query is as below.

```
var logDetails = (from c in db.ts_upldlog_content
join tbl in db.ts_upld_doc on c.upld_docid equals tbl.upld_docid
join doc in db.tm_doc_type on tbl.upld_doctypeid equals doc.doc_typeid
where 
(tbl.upld_clientid == clientId && tbl.upld_employeeid == employeeID && tbl.upld_empcitizenid == citizenId && tbl.upld_doctypeid == typeofDocument && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.updatedOn) >= start && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.updatedOn) < end)
    select new logdetails
    {
    //Getting all properties
    }).toList();
```

My problem is In the above query start and end are mandatory so i will get some value from UI. Let me explain one scenario. User will supply start and end and remaining will be null. My query will not yield results because I am doing && operation and my other fields may have some value in DB.
Lets conside below table.

```
clientID    EmployeeID   EmpCitiID  docType      Date
123         456          456        1            10/19/2016
```

When i Pass only Date my query will not work because I am doing && operation. so Is there any way to achieve this scenario? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the most upvoted answer to the duplicate.

Comment: If I understand correctly, some of the arguments (like `clientId`, `employeeID`, `citizenId` etc.) are optional. Please show the variables/method arguments declaration.

Comment: @GertArnold And this is even better :)

Comment: @GertArnold This query looks efficient , could make use of compiled query and cached query for better performance

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes clientId, employeeID, citizenId are optional. I can do it by using If else. Is it good approach to do it?

Comment: It's a very common way to build a query with predicates. There are many many similar answers at StackOverflow.

Comment: where EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.updatedOn) >= start && (tbl.upld_clientid == clientId || tbl.upld_employeeid == employeeID || tbl.upld_empcitizenid == citizenId || tbl.upld_doctypeid == typeofDocument)   I am not sure about this. What it will return? will it work?

Comment: Your question was about &&. This is an entirely different question. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tbl.upld_clientid == clientId && tbl.upld_employeeid == employeeID && tbl.upld_empcitizenid == citizenId && tbl.upld_doctypeid == typeofDocument && 

(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.updatedOn) >= start && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.updatedOn) < end )  )
```

missing parenthesis

Comment: No no I am not talking about syntex.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole but the code will fail

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: For some reason this answer was accepted, although it only points out a typo, which is not the issue.