# Entity Framework Search functionality with Dynamic SQL WHERE clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

hi guys i was using Dynamic SQL for search queries where i used to attach `WHERE` & `AND` clause piece by piece and form a statement, i recently came to below alternate for this, and life was amazing

[cool alternates of Dynamic WHERE-Clause](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21234/Implementing-Dynamic-WHERE-Clause-in-Static-SQL)

```
Select * From tblEmployees 
where EmployeeName = Coalesce(@EmployeeName, EmployeeName) AND
Department = Coalesce(@Department, Department ) AND
Designation = Coalesce(@Designation, Designation) AND
JoiningDate >= Coalesce(@StartDate, JoiningDate) AND 
JoiningDate <= Coalesce(@EndDate, JoiningDate) AND
Salary >= Coalesce(@Salary, Salary)
```

now the issue is since i implemented entity framework i need to achieve same with Linq queries. i have nullable Byte type and nullable boolean which i am  currently unable to handle

just like `Coalesce` my stupid attempt was 
`&& (s.Floors == deal.Floors.HasValue ? null : s.Floors)`

below code not matching any results

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Results(Deal deal, bool exactMatch)
    {
        List<Deal> deals;

        if (exactMatch)
        {
            deals = dataBase.Deals.Where(s =>
               (s.OwnerName.Contains(deal.OwnerName) || s.OwnerName == null)
            && (s.Rooms == deal.Rooms || s.Rooms == null)
            && (s.BathRooms == deal.BathRooms || s.BathRooms == null)
            && (s.Floors == deal.Floors || s.Floors == null)
            && (s.Builtin == deal.Builtin || s.Builtin == null)
            && (s.Kitchens == deal.Kitchens || s.Kitchens == null)
            && (s.DoubleUnit == deal.DoubleUnit || s.DoubleUnit == null)
            && (s.Corner == deal.Corner || s.Corner == null)
            && (s.Remarks.Contains(deal.Remarks) || s.Remarks == null)
            ).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            deals = dataBase.Deals.Where(s =>
               (s.OwnerName.Contains(deal.OwnerName) || s.OwnerName == null)
            || (s.Rooms == deal.Rooms || s.Rooms == null)
            || (s.BathRooms == deal.BathRooms || s.BathRooms == null)
            || (s.Floors == deal.Floors || s.Floors == null)
            || (s.Builtin == deal.Builtin || s.Builtin == null)
            || (s.Kitchens == deal.Kitchens || s.Kitchens == null)
            || (s.DoubleUnit == deal.DoubleUnit || s.DoubleUnit == null)
            || (s.Corner == deal.Corner || s.Corner == null)
            || (s.Remarks.Contains(deal.Remarks) || s.Remarks == null)
            ).ToList();
        }

        return View(deals);
    }
```

table has values like

```
id Bathroom Floors
1   1        2
2   1        4
3   2        6
4   3        1
```

i need results which has id 1 & 2 
for instance in front end user want to only fill bathroom field with "1" and leave floor field empty

Comment: @AntoinePelletier the difference is && and II

Comment: Not really the same is it. In your query your `coalesce` is on the parameter then taking the record value as the default if it is null. In your c# lambda you are checking if the parameter is the same as the table value and then checking if the table value is `null` but that omits the possibility of having a null value in the parameter.

Comment: @Igor my conversion of coalesce into c# code is a lame attempt, i just need coalesce like functionality in C#

Comment: You should remove these null checks from the expression body. Build the expression dynamically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716

Comment: Esp. for the `||` alternative you have to do it as I mentioned above. Note that it always returns all rows if even only one of the `= null` conditions is true.

Comment: @GertArnold i think predicate builder is more proper approach but for now @Igor showed me how to use `??` which translates to SQL CASE statement. will try to learn predicate builder also as shown in your shared link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the same. In your query your `coalesce` is on the parameter then taking the record value as the default if it is null. In your c# lambda you are checking if the parameter is the same as the table value and then checking if the table value is `null` but that omits the possibility of having a null value in the parameter.

Example

Sql

```
Department = Coalesce(@Department, Department )
```

would be

```
(s.Department == deal.Department || deal.Department == null)
```

not this which is what you have now

```
(s.Department == deal.Department || s.Department == null)
```

---

### Edit

If you wanted to duplicate the `COALESCE` expression you have now you could write it this way although I am not sure if it would decrease efficiency / performance.

```
(s.Department == (deal.Department ?? s.Department))
```

Comment: let me test this both ?? statement and (s.Department == deal.Department || deal.Department == null)

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz - ok.

Comment: `??` surely works i have checked `(s.Department == (deal.Department ?? s.Department))`  is converted in SQL case statements and suites my need in this search function. `([Extent1].[Department] = CASE WHEN (@p__linq__28 IS NULL) THEN [Extent1].[Department] ELSE @p__linq__28 END )`

Comment: Thanks alot for so quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing whether the field in the table equals the 'deal' property or the field is null rather than doing this:

```
s.Remarks.Contains(deal.Remarks) || deal.Remarks == null
```

If you do this, it should be the equivalent query.

You can do this cumulatively too. For example with the exact match case you can do:

```
deals = dataBase.Deals;
if (deal.OwnerName != null)
   deals = deals.Where(s => s.OwnerName.Contains(deal.OwnerName));

if (deal.Rooms != null)
  deals = deals.Where(s => s.Rooms == deal.Rooms)
```

That can make the resulting query more efficient. There's a similar way to do this with the non exact match through using unions. I don't know the syntax off hand.

Comment: Yes, an important aspect of the EF query, if you choose `s => ` then s will always refer to the table