# Entity Framework - Combining Predicates Dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Combining predicates like this causes stack overflow exception when EF query is executed. What is wrong with this?

```
Func<Item, bool> wherePredicate = i => i.isDeleted;
Func<Item, bool> wherePredicate2 = i => i.isExpired;

wherePredicate = i=> wherePredicate(i) || wherePredicate2(i);
```

Comment: Because `wherePredicate` calls itself...

Comment: @haim770 I have a dynamic scenario where the final predicate is determined by evaluating a lot of cases. How else can I combine them?

Comment: You are creating recursive lambda. But `Func<...>`s are not a proper predicate type for EF query anyway. For combining expression predicates, use any predicate builder library (from LinqKit or similar).

Comment: First, for EF you need `Expression<Func<Item, bool>>` in order to match `IQueryable`. You can use LinqKit to try and combine the predicates.

Comment: Build the predicate using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic where clause (OR) in Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621450/dynamic-where-clause-or-in-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 0):

You've created recursive loop, probably by accident.
With:

```
wherePredicate = i=> wherePredicate(i) || wherePredicate2(i);
```

you are just *defining anonymous function* in which `i=> wherePredicate(i) (...)` will be invoked, so it will invoke itself. The common rule like "everything on right side of '=' will be called before assignment" do not apply there as you might have thought, because a *function* it's what gets assigned, not its result.

What's more (you tagged Entity Framework) - it won't work in `.Where()` clause. Short answer - EF do not know how to invoke `Func<>` in database.
Long answer - see [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/#combining-expressions) which will help you in defining reusable predicates. Strange coincidance - your problem is almost literally explained in  "combining-expressions" section.