# How do you do complex "OR" filters at the database level in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Take the following SQL query:

```
select * from model where (Foo = 'a' and Bar = 'b') or (Foo = 'b' and Bar = 'b')
```

How would you translate this into an Entity Framework expression that works at the database level if you do not know the number of filters being applied?

I've made the following program to demonstrate what I'm talking about and what I have tried. I can not figure out a way to apply the filter without first bringing back everything from the DB without using Expression trees, which seems like overkill.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase("testdb")
    .Options;

using (var context = new TestContext(contextOptions))
{
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var models = new Model[]
    {
        new Model
        {
            Foo = "a",
            Bar = "a"
        },
        new Model
        {
            Foo = "a",
            Bar = "b"
        },
        new Model
        {
            Foo = "b",
            Bar = "a"
        },
        new Model
        {
            Foo = "b",
            Bar = "b"
        },
    };
    await context.AddRangeAsync(models);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var filters = new Filter[]
    {
        new Filter
        {
            Foo = "a",
            Bar = "b"
        },
        new Filter
        {
            Foo = "b",
            Bar = "b"
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Complex object:");
    try
    {
        var objectFilteredModels = await context.Models
            .Where(m => filters.Any(f => f.Foo == m.Foo && f.Bar == m.Bar))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDictionary:");
    var filterDictionary = filters.ToDictionary(f => f.Foo, f => f.Bar);
    try
    {
        var dictionaryFilteredModels = await context.Models
            .Where(m => filterDictionary.Keys.Any(k => k == m.Foo && filterDictionary[k] == m.Bar))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nSeparate arrays:");
    var foos = filters.Select(f => f.Foo).ToList();
    var bars = filters.Select(f => f.Bar).ToList();
    try
    {
        var arraysFilteredModels = await context.Models
            .Where(m => foos.Any(f => f == m.Foo && bars.ElementAt(foos.IndexOf(f)) == m.Bar))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nNon-DB query:");
    var allModels = await context.Models.ToListAsync();
    var filteredModels = allModels.Where(m => filters.Any(f => f.Foo == m.Foo && f.Bar == m.Bar)).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"no error, filtered model count: {filteredModels.Count}");
}


public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() { }
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Model> Models => Set<Model>();
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Bar { get; set; }
}    

public class Filter
{
    public string Foo { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You will need to use something like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to build `Expression` trees or something like [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) to translate a string representation of the `filters` array into an `Expresson` tree. There really isn't any way around it. I would recommend LINQKit or rolling your own simplified version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14621450/861716

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward translation of

```
select * from model where (Foo = 'a' and Bar = 'b') or (Foo = 'b' and Bar = 'b')
```

is

```
from m in db.Models 
where (m.Foo == 'a' && m.Bar == 'b') || (m.Foo == 'b' && m.Bar == 'b')
select m
```

Comment: Yes, but what if you don't know the contents/length of the `filters` object? I will edit my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to build the query:

```
   using LinqKit;

   try
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Model>(false);

        foreach (var item in filters)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Foo == item.Foo && x.Bar == item.Bar);
        }

        var result = context.Models.Where(predicate).ToList();

        result.Dump();

    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```