# Ignore part of the linq query if variable equals a specific value

Tags: linq

```
       var longlinq = viewModel.Where(x => (x.Systems.Storage == SelectOption || x.Systems.Laptop == SelectOption ||
                  x.Systems._2In1 == SelectOption ||
                  x.Systems.Convertible == SelectOption ) 
                  ||
                  (x.Component.Components == SelectOptionComp ||
                  x.Component.Boards == SelectOptionComp)
                  ||
                 ( x.Service.Services == SelectOptionSer ||
                  x.Service.DevelopmentTools_andServices == SelectOptionSer ) 
                  ||
                  (x.Software.Softwares == SelectOptionSoft ||
                  x.Software.Analytics == SelectOptionSoft) 
                  ||
                  (x.Application.Applications == SelectOptionApp ||
                  x.Application.PrintImaging_andOfficeAutomation ));
```

Let me explain my question with an example:
For instance `SelectOptionComp` equals `"-"`, then I want to ignore the parts where I used
`SelectOptionComp` in `longlinq` or set `SelectOptionComp` to `" "` in the `longlinq`.
I don't want to use `if`s because of large number of combinations.
How do I do that?

Comment: There are many questions and answers on how to add predicates (where filters) conditionally. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622200/861716

Comment: Use the ternary operator: `(SelectOptionComp == "-" ? true : (x.Component.Components == SelectOptionComp || x.Component.Boards == SelectOptionComp))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ternary operator `Use the ternary operator: (SelectOptionComp == "-" ? true : (x.Component.Components == SelectOptionComp || x.Component.Boards == SelectOptionComp))`